# Would this sentence sound more neutral with had?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Just take a look at these sentences:

> A: *"You got arrested for driving under influence?"*
> B: *"Yes . It happened a few days after my wife **(had)** told me that she wanted to separate, so I wasn't myself at the time."*

Would this be more natural with **'had'** ?

Comment: No, adding "had" would be wrong here. But you could say "Yes. My wife had just told me (a few days earlier) that she wanted to separate..."

Comment: Idiomatically, that's *driving under **the** influence [of alcohol or other intoxicants]*. But I disagree that there's anything "syntactically incorrect" about using Past Perfect *(**had**)* here. Both are fine - it's just that *in practice*, Simple Past is ***more likely***. Come to that, it wouldn't be "incorrect" to express the initial *It **had happened**...* using the Perfect form - that's just *very unlikely* (and would require a rather contrived context to become the ***preferred*** choice of tense).

Answer (score 1):

I mean, maybe a little bit.  The use of "had" pushes the action a little further into the past, which creates distance and therefore a little more detachment, but I wouldn't say especially neutral.